# Ionic4 + Codeigneter CORS ISSUE

Tags: cors, ionic4

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://somexxx.com//service/countries' from origin 'http://localhost:8100' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.**

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use https or its not going to work on newer Androids.

Second, the CORS problem is with the code running on somexxx.com not with your Ionic project.

The feed needs to support CORS because the webview that Ionic uses forces it to be enabled.